# Firebug doesn't show anything in any tab

Tags: firebug

I have created a Firefox profile to run Selenium tests. Until that day Firebug was showing all the contents in its tabs.

Now all the tabs are blank. I have tried reinstalling Firefox and Firebug, deleted the extra profile, set `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` and `browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` to `false`, though it's still not showing anything.

I noticed that some script is shown in front of the edit button, but it is not possible to expand it or see it within the tree view.

[image: Empty Inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's development is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) for several years now in favor of the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), so it breaks more and more with every version of Firefox because of changes in the internal browser APIs it uses.

On profiles where it is already installed, it [completely stops working with Firefox 57](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/), because starting from that version of Firefox only [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) are supported.

Note that Selenium doesn't require Firebug to run. If you use XPaths to identify elements, starting from Firefox 56 the built-in DevTools also have a feature to [copy the XPath of an element](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/developer-edition-devtools-update-now-with-photon-ui/).

Comment: Thanku Sebastian. I have downgraded the Firefox to version 55 no and its working. I will check for built-in DevTools feature to copy the XPath of an element.

Comment: Note that Firefox 56 already got [released on the 28th of September](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar#Past_branch_dates), so the XPath feature is already available.